# How to replace a string with another in line number 3 (n) and every n+6 (like 9, 15, 24 and so on) in Linux with sed or awk or any other programs?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have gathered a very big data in a `.txt` file containing around 6K lines, and I want to modify line 3 at first which is called now `n` and every `n+6`th line, like 9, 15, 24 and so on.

This is an example of the current state:

```
domain_name = {'name': 'aaa.pro'
'register': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'abogado'
'register': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'academy'
'register': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'currency': USD
```

I want the result be something like:

```
domain_name = {'name': 'aaa.pro'
'register': 159.00
'renew': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'abogado'
'register': 40.50
'renew': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'academy'
'register': 34.50
'renew': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'currency': USD
```

So that the line number 3 which is `n`, and then line numbers 9, 15 and so on (n+6) that contain `register` string should be replaced by `renew` string.

I have read `sed` and `awk` manual but I did not understand how to exactly reach this.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v n="3" 'FNR==n{sub(/register/,"renew");n+=6} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Mentioning `-v n="3"` to create variable named `n` which has value as `3`. Then checking condition `FNR==n` to see if current line number is same as `n` then go inside block `{...}` and using `sub` substitute register with renew there,then adding 6 to current value of n and saving it into `n` itself. `1` will print the current line.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '3~6s/register/renew/' file
```

Starting at line 3 and every 6 lines thereafter, substitute `renew` for `register` and edit the file in place.